# Firebase OAuth error when trying to set up sample web application

Tags: oauth, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm getting the following error message in my web browser

> firebase.js:75 Uncaught Error: This domain is not authorized for OAuth
>   operations for your Firebase project. Edit the list of authorized
>   domains from the Firebase console.

I have downloaded the Firebase [web app sample](https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/) to my local machine, pastet the snippet from the firebase console into the .html file of the "database" sample project and enabled Google as authentication method in the console.

Removing the snippet removes the error, but than it doesn't work at all (unsuprisingly).

Also tried with the "auth" sample project.

I have noticed there is a [service disruption reported](https://status.firebase.google.com/) by Firebase, but unsure if that is the reason.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for development on your computer (local) you need to be running the project from a local http server - not just from a file. ie the url needs to be something like http://localhost.... not file://.....

then you need to add "localhost" to the firebase console under auth > signin methods > OAuth redirect domains

Comment: I have above steps included/configure however I still get error described in this question. https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1444